# CSS Menu CSS Confusion

Tags: html, css

I have got the following HTML but I am unsure how to code the CSS so that when I hover the main `li` the drop down menu shows.

```
        <li><a href="#">#</a>
            <ul class="sub_menu">
                <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">#</li></li>
                </ul>
            </li>`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
li ul {
    display: none;
}

li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

This won't work in IE6 but nobody cares about that anymore.

Comment: Some clients of mine cares about it, and even too much. But your answer is great ! +1 :)

Comment: My company has about 30,000 corporate IE client users who would say otherwise. IE6 is easily 60% of our traffic.   EDIT: OK, I lied; I just checked our analytics, and it's down to 52% so far this month.

Comment: @ryandenki sorry about your horrible clients. I wish you the best of luck.